# How do I write a query using Elasticsearch Java API where the elements in a JSON list contains some of the elements in a List<>?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, search-engine, java

I have this JSON-object:

```
{
"title": "Food",
"Dishes": [
    "Pancakes",
    "Tacos"
],
"rating": "5"
}
```

And I need to write a query using Elasticsearch's Java API that will match JSON-objects where the "Dishes" field contains either the string "Pancakes" or "Soup" (hence the JSON above should match). The elements that I search for are stored in a list like this:

```
List<String> findElems = Arrays.asList("Pancakes", "Soup");
```

I have tried to use QueryBuilders but I cant find out how to write a query that matches JSON-files where the "Dishes" list contains one or more of the elements in findElems.

Comment: Does `boolQuery().should(termQuery("Dishes", "Pancakes"), termQuery("Dishes", "Soup"))` not work (should is bascially an 'or', iirc)?

Answer (score 1):

Use terms query to do that,

```
    List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Pancakes");
    list.add("Tacos");
    QueryBuilders.termsQuery("Dishes", list);
```

HOpe it helps!